# style a label tag based on the class of the elment it is a label "for"

Tags: html, css

I tried:

html:

```
<p><label for="address1">Address 1:</label> <input type="text" class="required" id="address1" name="address1" value="" /></p>
```

css:

```
input.required + label { color: #c00; }
```

however this does not seem to be working... Am i doing it wrong?

Firefox 8 testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` selector is a sibling selector. `input + label` applies a style to a `<label>` element which is the next element directly after `<input>`, as seen at http://jsfiddle.net/Wg7Rr/.

There is no CSS to select the previous sibling, unfortunately.

Instead of applying `required` to the input element, you can attach the class to the label, o the parent, then use:

```
label.required + input { color: #c00; }   /*<label class=required /><input>*/
.required > label { color: #c00}          /*<p class=required><label /><input>*/
```

Comment: I like how you explained /why/ what i was doing wont work. Its that whole Next vs. Previous thing thats f*cking me on this! I'll stick to doing <p class="required">....</p>. The reason why I wanted to set this up this way is I'm using jQuery to maninipulate form fields, and certain fields are required based on which country is selected. Its easy for me to change the class of the input's via the jquery code while I'm showing / hiding the appropriate elements, but its a lot of extra code / selectors to have to update a completely different element every time, for each of the changed fields.

Answer (score 6):

Try using an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors), like this:

```
label[for='address1'] { color: #c00; }
```

This works in the following browsers

- Firefox 8.
- IE 8 +
- Chrome
- Safari 5
- Opera 11.52

Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TeU7U/

Comment: This would work, however not really what i'm looking for. I want to be able to say any label of any input with class required, should be red. If i used this code, my css file would be cluttered - i'm trying to minimize clutter with cool tricks like what I'm trying. If its not possible, its not possible, i guess I was just looking to make sure it wasn't possible.

Comment: I had to hide an input that was contained by a label, using the sibling '+' selector did not help me. Using the 'for' attribute as showed here did :)

Answer (score 2):

`input.required + label` will actually match any label wich *immediately follows* an input with the class required. Wich is why it won't work in your case.

You could use something like `label[for='address1']`, but if you want to style every label that's associated with a required input, you could simply add your required class to the wrapping `p`. You could then use `p.required label` as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Not sure how is it with compatibly with older browsers and performance issues.

The HTML:

```
<label>Address 1: <input type="text" class="required" id="address1" name="address1" value="" /></label>
```

the CSS:

```
label > .required{
background:#900;

}
```

and a fiddle to go along

http://jsfiddle.net/S1l3/2eVQ8/

Comment: I'd be nice to have an explanation. "no lol just no" not that great. Just sayin'.